# what is the difference between scale transformation and coordinate system transformation

Tags: r, statistics

in the documentation for coord_trans function that is used for coordinates transformation it says that the difference between this function and scale_x_log10 is transformation occurs after statistics, and scale transformation occurs before , I didn't get the point [check documentation here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_trans.html) .
and how the data is plotted using both methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote from the documentation you supplied tells us that scale transformation occurs *before* any statistical analysis pertaining to the plot.

The example provided in the documentation is especially informative, since it involves regression analysis. In the case of scale transformation, i.e. using

```
d <- subset(diamonds, carat > 0.5)
qplot(carat, price, data = d, log="xy") + geom_smooth(method="lm"),
```

[image: scale transform]

the scales are first transformed and *then* the regression analysis is performed. Minimizing the SS of the errors is done on transformed axes (or transformed data), which you would only want if you thought that there is a linear relationship between the logs of variables. The result is a straight line on a log-log plot, even though the axes are not scaled 1:1 (hard to see in this example).

Meanwhile, when using

```
qplot(carat, price, data = d) +
geom_smooth(method="lm") +
coord_trans(x = "log10", y = "log10")
```

[image: coord transform]

the regression analysis is performed first on untransformed data (and axes, that is, independently of the plot) and then everything is plotted with transformed coordinates. This results in the regression line not being straight at all, because **its** equation (or rather the coordinates  of its points) is transformed in the process of coordinate transformation.

This is illustrated further in the documentation by using

```
library(scales)
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, log="xy") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  coord_trans(x = exp_trans(10), y = exp_trans(10))
```

[image: back-transform]

Where you can see that 1. using a scale transformation, 2. fitting a line and 3. transforming coordinates back to the original (linear) system, this doesn't produce a straight line as it should. In the first scenario, you actually fitted an exponential curve which **looked** straight on a log-log plot.

Comment: What does it mean to say "minimizing the SS of the errors is done on transformed axes"?

Comment: @whopper510 It means finding a line that is "closest" (with respect to some chosen metric) to the points. When only the axes, but not the data, are transformed, this would not give you a result you usually want in linear regression.

Comment: Right, I guess I should have been more specific in my question. I understand the idea of finding a line of best fit by minimizing the value of some cost function (e.g., SS error), but what role do the *axis* play in the process? In learning regression, I've only seen the observed data play a role (though I guess the axis are used implicitly). 

How does ggplot make the axis explicit in the regression? Are the predicted *y*'s on the transformed scale or something?

Comment: @whopper510 Well, transforming the axis or transforming the data are really one and the same thing, just looked at from different angles. You were right that the thing about scales and data was confusing, I tried to make it clearer.